# WCF Data Service with custom filter

Tags: c#-4.0, wcf-data-services, odata

I am creating a service using WCF Data Services and Entity Framework 4.1 code first. I have a requirement to do some filtering based on a uri segment. Basically, we have a multi-tenant database and need to require that the string representation of the tenant id be passed as part of the uri. For example a uri would look something like this:

```
http://myservice.com/client123/Users
```

Where the `Client123` will then be used to create the context filtering to only that clients data.

I was pointed in the direction of the OData sample code at `http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk` I see the code where the default data is being created and cached with a sessionid (I have added the logic for session management as well). However, the way it is being done with the DSPContext etc. it seems like much of this should not be required for an entity framework based implementation. (At least my understanding is that creating a custom context should not be required if you are using Entity Framework.)

Is anybody aware of a good example of doing this sort of implementation using a standard Entity Framework based data source? Or alternatively, could you give me advice of how to modify the existing sdk code? I am mainly stuck on the metadata creation (is this even required?) And the resource creation.

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: I am really stuck with this. I have tried acheiving this route by registering a serviceroute as well. the problem with that is that placeholders do not appear to be supported in service route.

Please help! :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF based service where the service will always look the same, regardless of the client ID, then you don't need any fancy custom providers. Just use the trick from the SDK to get the right client ID, expose a "normal" EF based WCF DS Service and in the DataService.CreateDataSource override use the client ID to create the right EF context for that client.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would I then do a uritemplate match to extract the id and pass it on? I think(know) I am missing something that should be obvious.

Comment: In your override of CreateDataSource you need to somehow get the client id. There are several ways (depends on your exact host). One way is to inspect the request URI and get it from there. The other might be the trick the SDK sample uses with sessions.

Comment: I was able to get what I need by using a uriteplate and getting the boundparameter. However, I still get a resource not found for the client123.

Comment: Did you debug where the 404 is comming from? Just attach a debugger and let it stop on all exceptions. The 404 will be thrown as an exception at some point.

Comment: Yes I actually did attempt to debug with break on all exceptions set and I receive no breaks. What I believe is happening is that it is attempting to find an EF resource Client123 which does not exist. Do I need to remove this from the URL somehow? Sorry, I am a newbie to this routing piece.

Comment: Is the Client123 segment before or after the .svc in the path? If it's before, then I don't really know how to do that (IIS/ASP.NET, not my expertise). If it's after the .svc you should see an exception comming from WCF DS.